# How to display system message outside of template in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla-component

Joomla Geeks!

Please help me. Web designers created design for Joomla, where

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

should be located inside of custom component's view (default.php). It's because of divs nesting, I can't change anything.

Nevertheless, I have to find a solution to include **Joomla system messages** in component's view (**default.php**) instead of template's index.php, how to do that? Is it possible?

**UPD:** I've solved the problem, but now I need to override this code:

```
<dl id="system-message">
  <dt class="message">MESSAGE_TYPE</dt>
  <dd class="message message fade">
    <ul>
      <li>MESSAGE_TEXT</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

with this one:

```
<div class="message">
  <span class="jsMessage info_message">
    <span>
      MESSAGE_TEXT <a class="close jsCloseMessage" href="javascript:void(0)"></a
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Should I use **templates/mytemplate/html/modules.php** file for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$document = & JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('message');
$msg=$renderer->render();
```